# NullPointerException in main method?

Tags: java, class, object, methods, nullpointerexception

```
 if(tempCard.getSuitValue() == PlayingCard.CLUBS || tempCard.getSuitValue() == PlayingCard.SPADES)
```

this is the line that is giving me a NullPointerException

```
PlayingCard redCard, blackCard, tempCard;
```

tempCard is declared as a varible of object PlayingCard

```
public PlayingCard(int newFace, int newSuit)
{
    faceValue = newFace; 
    suitValue = newSuit; 
}
```

this is the constructor for object PlayingCard, as well as the parameters for it

```
public int getFaceValue()
{
    return faceValue;
}
public int getSuitValue()
{
    return suitValue; 
}
```

these methods give values to the getSuitValue method used in the statement at the very top

```
public final static int CLUBS = 0;
public final static int DIAMONDS = 1;
public final static int HEARTS = 2; 
public final static int SPADES = 3;
```

these are the constant values for the cards in the deck.

I have gone through every method and constructor that is used in the line that results in the NullPointerException.  If anyone wants to see all 4 classes, I can post them at their request.

Comment: I think only possibility is `tempCard` is null. Please debug and check whether `tempCard` is null or not.

Comment: 'tempCard' is obviously 'null'. So do something about it.

Comment: @Tom maybe the NPE comes from an Integer unboxing because of ==

Comment: @RC. Both sides work with the primitive 'int' so where should that 'Integer' come from?

Comment: `return suitValue;`  <= this might be an "Integer" (@Grogi we don't see the whole class..)

Comment: @RC In the constructor it is initialized from an `int`. No, it cannot be `null` - unless the OP really really wants it to be...

Comment: @RC. Then the part "because of ==" would still be incorrect ;P. But this would also mean that Op doesn't use this mentioned constructor and I don't think that Op even know that 'Integer' exists, because he might be a beginner.

Comment: Have you initialized created new instance with new operator on tempCard? make sure it is done....